# How to display values in grids(Struts 2.x)?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery

When run on tomcat server(local server) values are getting in grid(Strusts 2.x),but when i deploy on server(10.x.x.x) grid values are not getting.

Comment: does the action called by grid? does the json result created?

Answer (score 0):

Probably issue mentioned at [Only one getter works on the page after uploading to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22880555/only-one-getter-works-on-the-page-after-uploading-to-the-server/22892193#22892193)

It may be a bug in struts 2.3.1.1. and OGNL 3.0.3 try to upgrade struts